# How to display both percentage and value in pie chart in obiee11g

Tags: obiee

My requirement is to display both(percentage,value) on same pie chart.I am able to show either value or percentage but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.Please check the screen shot.[image]

Comment: check and implement its coming properly.

Comment: Thank you sir. yeah it's working fine. I will contact you if I need some other help in OBIEE as I am new bee in OBIEE :) Thanks once again.